# GraphQL server always returning empty array in data

Tags: reactjs, service, graphql, localhost

I have setup locally a GraphQL service and a backend service that holds my data. This entire setup is also present in the cloud development environment. I am trying to debug an issue, and for that reason I am hitting my local backend service using the Graphql playground. But strangely whenever I am configuring the local service url in graphql, it never hits the service and simply responds with an empty array. But the moment I change the url to point to the dev environment service, it gives the expected data response.

The local service is working fine, as I have already tested it using Postman, and it does give the correct results. Not really sure what is going wrong here. Is there any setting/caching that is causing this? I have tried clearing cache multiple times, but that does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: description is not enough ... more details, code, configs/responses, logs ... it can be anything ... for now the answer is "It may or may not work"

Answer (score 0):

ok, so figured it out. The problem was the company proxy running on my machine. It was blocking the localhost:8095 url going out from graphql. When I ran it after disabling the proxy, it all worked fine. Not sure why it was blocking the localhost. Thanks everyone